# how to naming RESTful address if the API is not pure doing CRUD

Tags: restful-url

I know the basic logic of POST, GET, PUT, and DELETE, and the whole URL should be a noun, but sometimes we are not really just doing CRUD, for example, if I got an API to help users to reset their password by sending a forgot password email password, how to name it.

[POST or PUT] [https://www.example.com/users/{user_id}/forgot-password](https://www.example.com/users/%7Buser_id%7D/forgot-password) looks not noun
[POST or PUT] [https://www.example.com/users/{user_id}/password-forgot](https://www.example.com/users/%7Buser_id%7D/password-forgot) looks more make sense?

Another example, if I want to cancel an order, it has a lot of processes, not only delete an order, so I can't use only `DELETE https://www.example.com/orders/{order_id}`.

Should it be:
[POST] [https://www.example.com/orders/{order_id}/cancel](https://www.example.com/orders/%7Border_id%7D/cancel) looks not full noun URL

Comment: You can POST to generate reset link. Then use PUT to reset the password. POST usually for creations, PUT for updating few fields/data. Its upto you.

Comment: forgot-password or password-forgot, which more make sense?

Comment: forgot-password . I am not a native English speaker, but this looks grammatical correct. :)

Comment: if I  want to cancel `update-email` thing, 1. /update-email/cancel, 2. update-email-cancel, 3. /cancel-update-email which one is better

Comment: Haha. I think you might need to post in another English exchange or something. like I said, Its upto you. and not English teacher.

Comment: I know forgot password is what we normally say, but hard to make it present correctly on the URL for the RESTful rule. QQ